# Send email after cancel order from frontend

Tags: magento-1, order-email

I am working on sending email after order has been cancelled by customer. Order status is being changed but I can not send email.

My controllers looks like this:

```
public function cancelAction()
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(
        $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id')
    );

    if ($order->getId()) {
        if (Mage::helper('cancelorder/customer')->canCancel($order)) {
            try {
                $order->cancel();

                if ($status = Mage::helper('cancelorder/customer')->getCancelStatus($store)) {
                    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', $status)
                        ->setIsCustomerNotified(1);

                }

                $order->save();
                // If sending transactionnal email is enabled in system configuration, we send the email
                if(Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('sales/cancel/send_email')) {
                    $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail();
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')
                    ->addSuccess($this->__('Your order has been canceled.'));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')
                    ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot cancel your order.'));
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')
                ->addError($this->__('Cannot cancel your order.'));
        }

        $this->_redirect('sales/order/history');

        return;
    }

    $this->_forward('noRoute');
}
```

Comment: this mail send through cron. So active your cron.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible problems:

1. The CRON is not working properly
2. Sending email is disabled in the `System > Configuration`. Check it in the store view configuration menu `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order Comments > Enabled`:
   [image: Config]

PS: You have **Undefined variable `$store`** in the code:

```
if ($status = Mage::helper('cancelorder/customer')->getCancelStatus($store)) {
```